# Medizinische Fachbegriffe für den Inhalt des Darms gesucht

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request

Ich will beschreiben, wir man nach einem Schnitt in den Bauch die Wunde reinigt. Dabei habe ich mich gefragt, ob es für den Inhalt des Darms, je nach Verdauungsfortschritt, unterschiedliche medizinische Fachbegriffe gibt. Es geht also um die Stadien zwischen Nahrung und Kot. Suche nach Begriffen in der Humanmedizin, nehme aber auch gerne welche aus der Jägersprache (die müssen sich ja auch mit den Zeug auseinandersetzen, wenn sie beim öffnen der Bauchdecke einen Fehler machen oder falsch geschossen haben), oder der Veterinärmedizin.

Comment: Medizinische Fachbegriffe sind selten in Deutsch, sondern eher Latein oder Griechisch. Bist Du Dir sicher, dass dieses die richtige SE Seite für diese Frage ist? Nur dass die Frage auf Deutsch gestellt wurde legitimiert sie leider noch nicht für German Language. Ich denke [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) wäre hier besser geeignet.

Comment: Ich suche nach Worten die ein Arzt (Jäger/Veterinär) im deutschen Sprachraum benutzen würde. Sind Fachbegriffe, die ursprünglich aus einer anderen Sprache kommen nicht deutsch? Wo zieht man da die Grenze?

Comment: Das hängt möglicherweise vom Fachgebiet ab. Ein altes Handwerk z.B. wird vorzugsweise deutsche Fachbegriffe nutzen. Einen medizinischen Fachbegriff, wie bspw. _Ulcus_ oder _Sinusitis_ wird man wohl schwerlich als "deutsches Wort" einordnen können. Bei Lehnwörtern ist das eine andere Sache.

Comment: Einverstanden, ich lasse die Frage trotzdem noch ein bisschen drin, denn ich kann nicht ausschließen, das es nicht doch vielleicht einen deutschen Begriff gibt. Besonders bei den Jägern bin ich zuversichtlich, die haben für alles ihre eigenen Wörter. Außerdem: Mund, Nahrung und Stuhl sind auch deutsch. Jagd und Medizin auf alte Berufe, also stehen die Chancen gut würde ich sagen.

Comment: Was sagen denn die medizinischen Lehrbücher (z.B. der Chirurgen) dazu? Der Psychrembel beschreibt primär ja nur die bekannten Krankheiten. Jedenfalls würde ich in den Lehrbüchern suchen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ich verstehe diese Argumentation nicht. Wieso sollte _Sinusitis_ kein deutsches Wort sein? Steht sogar im Duden. Das Gleiche gilt für _Chymus_. In meinen Augen ist german.SE die richtige Seite, weil es ja um Fachbegriffe geht, wie sie von deutschen Sprecher\*innen verwendet werden. Ich bin dafür, die Frage offen zu halten.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Ja, die Frage sollte nicht geschlossen werden - aber nicht aus dem Grund, weil auch medizinische Fachbegriffe im Duden stehen, sondern weil Philipp ausdrücklich nach Worten nicht-lateinisch/griechischen  Ursprungs fragt und explizit Jägersprache erwähnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ein Wort habe ich schon selbst gefunden. Vielleicht gibt es noch mehr? https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chymus

Comment: Da Links sich ändern oder verschwinden können solltest du den Inhalt hier zusammenfassen. [siehe hier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)